# Get the "PRIMARY STATIC WEBSITE ENDPOINT" from Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

In the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) I can look up a Storage Account and go to the Settings/Properties section and see the list of properties which contains `PRIMARY STATIC WEBSITE ENDPOINT`. Alternatively I can see the same information in the Settings/Static Website section marked as `Primary endpoint`

How do I get that with the [Azure PowerShell "Az" module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azps-1.1.0)?

Alternatively, I can [piece together the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#how-does-it-work) if I can find the zone information from somewhere. e.g. From this template `https://<ACCOUNT_NAME>.<ZONE_NAME>.web.core.windows.net/<FILE_NAME>`

Or is there another way I can get the information I need easily from within a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the PRIMARY STATIC WEBSITE ENDPOINT details using Az module with the below command or snippet.

```
(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCEGROUPNAME> -Name <STORAGEACCOUNTNAME>|select PrimaryEndpoints).PrimaryEndpoints.Web
```

For illustration, please see below screenshot.
[image]

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you, that's absolutely fantastic - I don't even have to repeatedly call it as it always gives me the result.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a sort of solution. It doesn't feel ideal. I would hope that there is a more concise and less fragile way to get this information but the following gets me what I am looking for in PowerShell, after a fashion.

I had to install an additional PowerShell module, that I would have thought be installed already, but...

```
Install-Module Az.ResourceGraph
```

And then I was able to use the [Search-AzGraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resourcegraph/Search-AzGraph?view=azps-1.1.0) function like this:

```
(Search-AzGraph -Subscription <SubscriptionGuidHere> `
    -Query "where type == 'microsoft.storage/storage
accounts' | where name == '<StorageAccountName>' | limit 1")`
    .aliases `
    .'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/primaryEndpoints.web'
```

I don't know if this is the best query syntax, as I managed to cobble it together from a variety of documentation I've only just found and a bit of brute force and ignorance.

The above is also a little fragile - I suspect there is caching going on somewhere, or maybe where this function gets its information from simply hasn't got the latest information. If you run this too quickly after creating the storage account you get nothing back, but wait a few seconds and it returns the information. The longest I've had to wait for the above to bring back results is about 30 seconds.

If anyone has a better solution, I'd love to go down that route instead, as `Search-AzGraph` is probably okay for monitoring, but not good when you want to get the name of an end point so the next part of a script can use that to continue what it is doing.

Comment: From the documentation you can query the endpoint url using az cli: `az storage account show -n <ACCOUNT_NAME> -g <RESOURCE_GROUP> --query "primaryEndpoints.web" --output tsv`

Comment: Not sure how the new Az powershell modules works, it supposed to work like the az cli but never tried